# TSQL How can I reuse a record in subqueries

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql, subquery

I have a query similar to the following where I need to return a few fields from another table as subqueries. Is there a way I can only call the query to TABLE2 once and use the results of that query to populate the various fields I need?  I'm looking for something similar to how you can use a let statement in LINQ.  Thanks.

```
select

(select field1 from TABLE2 where id = 1) as field1,
(select field2 from TABLE2 where id = 1) as field2,
(select field3 from TABLE2 where id = 1) as field3,
(select field4 from TABLE2 where id = 1) as field4 

from mainTable where p1 = @p1
```

Comment: There are several ways you could accomplish this. You could use a cte, a derived table or most likely you could simply join your tables. But a big kudos for realizing this is not very efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use OUTER APPLY:

```
select

x.field1 as field1,
x.field2 as field2,
x.field3 as field3,
x.field4 as field4 

from mainTable as mt
outer apply (select field1, field2, field3, field4 from TABLE2 where id = 1) as x
where p1 = @p1
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that variables are the closest to the LINQ *let* clause. For example:

```
declare @field1 bigint;
declare @field2 nvarchar(64);

select @field1 = field1, @field2=field2 from TABLE2 where id = 1;


select @field1, @field2, SomeOtherField from mainTable
where p1 = @p1;
```

**Of course you need set proper types of variables.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select t.field1, t.field2, ...
from mainTable 
cross join (select field1, field2, ... from TABLE2 where id = 1) as t
where p1 = @p1
```

I assume that the subquery used in the `cross join` operation returns exactly one record.

Comment: If `where id = 1` is False or Unknown and `where p1 = @p1` is True then original query will return at least one row but this solution ... not.

Comment: 2 rows CROSS JOIN 0 rows = 0 rows